# SQL Select where value = to another select

Tags: join, select, sum, firebird

I have two tables. Orders, and OrderParts. One Order can have many OrderParts.

I want a list of all the `order.customerID` where the number of `OrderParts ordered = Total_number_parts` in the order table.

Below is where i have got to so far, but where do i put the `where sum(partqty)=total_number_parts` bit!!

```
Select a.customerID, a.Total_number_parts
From Orders a
Join (Select sum(PartQty) from OrderParts Group by customerID) B
   on B.customerID = a.customerID
Group By a.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. Adding to this slighly more..  If some customers have placed more than one order, how could i select the customerIDs where sum(a.total_number_parts) for each customerID = sum(partqty) for this customerID ??  i.e. select all the customerIDs that have received all their parts. Thank you

Comment: Incrementally changing your question isn't generally a good idea. It becomes difficult to select a single post that's the best answer to your question, because different posts are addressing different versions. I'd recommend seeing if you can get to the answer yourself, and asking another question (you can include a pointer to this one) if you can't (and if it hasn't been addressed already).

Comment: Ok no problem, thanks. I am new to using forums so still learning. Thanks, Simon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare sum of two select results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195193/compare-sum-of-two-select-results)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for this work:

```
WITH ctSum AS
(
    SELECT   customerId, SUM(PartQty) as TotalQty
    FROM     OrdersParts
    GROUP BY customerID
)
SELECT a.customerID, a.Total_number_parts
FROM   Orders a
JOIN   ctSum b
ON     b.customerID = a.customerID
WHERE  a.Total_number_parts = b.TotalQty;
```

Or if you prefer another syntax:

```
SELECT a.customerID, a.Total_number_parts
FROM   Orders a
JOIN   (SELECT   customerId, SUM(PartQty) as TotalQty
        FROM     OrdersParts
        GROUP BY customerID) b
ON     b.customerID = a.customerID
WHERE  a.Total_number_parts = b.TotalQty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HAVING` clause and get rid of the derived table:

```
SELECT a.customerID, SUM(b.PartQty)
FROM   Orders a
JOIN   OrdersParts b
    ON b.customerID = a.customerID
GROUP BY a.customerID
HAVING a.Total_number_parts = SUM(b.PartQty);
```

`HAVING` is evaluated after `GROUP BY` contrary to `WHERE`, and this is why you can use aggregate functions in the `HAVING` clause.